# Необходимо вытянуть актуальнуюю цену(по дате) из БД (PostgtreSql)

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

В общем есть две таблицы - Materials и Material_Cost.

Во второй таблице следующие:

> [Material_Cost]
>
> ID - PK
>
> cost - numeric
>
> data - date
>
> material_id - FK->Materials

Мне необходимо сделать выборку всех материалов (с актуальной ценой), для начала написал:

```
select mc.id, mc.cost, max(mc.data), mc.material_id from material_cost mc
```

Орет что,

> column "mc.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Добавил group by - логика запроса себя исчерпала.

Дошел потом еще до такого варианта, но он тоже не подошел (выводит все цены товаров)

```
select  tmp.name, tmp.global_unit, tmp.cost, g.name as "gname", c.name as "cname" from 
       (
            select m.global_unit,m.name,m.id, max(mc.data), mc.cost, m.group_id, m.category_id from material_cost mc
            inner join materials m on m.id = mc.material_id group by m.id,mc.cost
        )tmp
```

inner join groups g on g.ID = tmp.group_id 
inner join category c on c.ID = tmp.category_id

Может у кого-то будут какие-нибудь идеи?) А то я завис...

Comment: `WHERE ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY material_id ORDER BY data DESC) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будут. `DISTINCT ON` по материалам с ценами по убыванию.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(mc.material_id)
  mc.id, mc.cost, mc.data, mc.material_id
  FROM material_cost mc
  ORDER BY mc.material_id, mc.data DESC
```

См. [документацию о `DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

Comment: Идеально, спасибо! Нужно было только добавить GROUP BY.

Comment: @Takeshi8059 `GROUP BY`? Куда, зачем?

Comment: вот такую ошибку выдает ERROR:  column "mc.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @Takeshi8059 а, тю. Уберите `GROUP BY`, это я забыл убрать `max` Обновил ответ :)

Comment: о, так намного приятнее, спасибо большое :)